# Card-swipe based interface for macOS: Human Interface Guidelines

Tags: desktop-application, human-interface-guideline, animation, mac-os-x, apple

I was looking towards creating an app for solving an issue I've had with quickly sorting files. The interface would be similar to Tinder's but for files (images, system files etcetera).

Reading Apple's HIG, it seems that "Excessive Animation", or applications where animation makes the focal point of the app are likely to be rejected.

Would this UX be too mobile-like for a desktop? Would it be inadvisable?

Comment: Tinder is published on the App Store, no?

Comment: I'm talking about the Mac App Store, which has a different HIG.

Comment: Ah...misread. My bad.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you might face is not mainly in the transition between states (although it might also be) but in the way the user interacts with the app.

In non-touch devices, drag is used to change the position of an element. This can be to displace the content inside a canvas (like in a map) or to move an element to a new place.

Swipe feels natural for touch devices because it is a natural interaction (think of swiping the pages of a magazine). But, in my opinion, swipe doesn't feel as natural with a mouse because it implies mousedown + mousemove + mouseup. So if there is no need to use such interaction in a desktop then try not to rely on it.

Comment: I agree. It seems like the interaction itself might be fine, but rather than swiping, use buttons or regions, and/or keyboard arrows.

Comment: I was wanting to use keyboard arrows and display the feedback as a swipe animation on-screen. But really, that'd be the bulk of the app. In a single view application, maybe without an enclosing window (like some white space around the cards), it might seem animation focussed.